# Is there a way to open the honoree section by default?

Tags: civicontribute, honoree

I would like to have the honoree section on a civicontribute page default to being open, instead of having the user find and click on the honoree title in order to see the fields. They could still close it if they don't want to use it. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will require a small bit of code -> javascript (to check that box on load of the form).